# What does a job mean in initctl and how is it used?

Tags: linux, init

I searched every where, manual says usage:

initctl status JOB[key=value]

WHat is a JOB actually, no one describe it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the list of JOB or instances with list option. As man page says:

Requests a list of the known jobs and instances, outputs the status of each
   to standard output.

Use initctl list to see the JOB or instances.